# Python ArangoDB insertion of objects not completed after method is run

Tags: python, python-3.x, arangodb, python-arango

I use [arango-orm](https://github.com/threatify/arango-orm) (which uses [python-arango](https://github.com/joowani/python-arango) in the background) in my Python/ArangoDB back-end. I have set up a small testing util that uses a remote database to insert test data, execute the unit tests and remove the test data again.
I insert my test data with a Python for loop. Each iteration, a small piece of information changes based on a generic object and then I insert that modified generic object into ArangoDB until I have 10 test objects. However, after that code is run, my test assertions tell me I don't have 10 objects stored inside my db, but only 8 (or sometimes 3, 7 or 9). It looks like `pythong-arango` runs these queries asynchronously or that `ArangoDB` already replies with an OK before the data is actually inserted. Anyone has an idea of what is going on? When I put in a sleep of 1 second after all data is inserted, my tests run green. This obviously is no solution.

This is a little piece of example code I use:

```
def load_test_data(self) -> None:
    # This method is called from the setUp() method.
    logging.info("Loading test data...")
    for i in range(1, 11):
        # insertion with data object (ORM)
        user = test_utils.get_default_test_user()
        user.id = i
        user.username += str(i)
        user.name += str(i)
        db.add(user)

        # insertion with dictionary
        project = test_utils.get_default_test_project()
        project['id'] = i
        project['name'] += str(i)
        project['description'] = f"Description for project with the id {i}"
        db.insert_document("projects", project)
    # TODO: solve this dirty hack
    sleep(1)

def test_search_by_user_username(self) -> None:
    actual = dao.search("TestUser3")
    self.assertEqual(1, len(actual))
    self.assertEqual(3, actual[0].id)
```

Then my db is created like this in a separate module:

```
client = ArangoClient(hosts=f"http://{arango_host}:{arango_port}")
test_db = client.db(arango_db, arango_user, arango_password)
db = Database(test_db)
```

EDIT: 
I had not put the `sync` property to `true` upon collection creation, but after changing the collection and setting it to `true`, the behaviour stays exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with the people of ArangoDB, I learned that views are not updatet as quickly as collections. Thye have given me an internal `SEARCH option` which also waits for synching views. Since it's an internal option, only used for unit testing, they high discourage the use of it. For me, I only use it for unit testing.